# Firebase Test Lab - Problems when two fields have the same class

Tags: firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to run this test on Firebase Test Lab Robo Test

```
 [
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1539204374357,
    "replacementText": "11111111111",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText",
        ...
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1539204421008,
    "replacementText": "Qwer123*",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText",
        ...
]
```

The both field classes are the same (because they are custom fields), so the Firebase test lab can't differ them. The elementDescriptor are the same. Do you know how to differ them?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to differentiate between the widgets by defining the "text" or "resourceId" field in the element descriptor. E.g. when you want to use the resource id to identify a specific widget:

```
....
"elementDescriptors": [
  {
    "resourceId": "com.example.myapp:id/my_edit_text"
  }
]
....
```